# jQuery animate an object using declared positions

Tags: jquery

here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SunMercury/pmhFv/

How can I declare an object id and startValueX, startValueY, endValueX, endValueY first

then it will animate using my declared values?

animateMe($('#box1'), 2000);

to

animateMe($('#box1'), startValueX, startValueY, endValueX, endValueY, 2000);

Comment: Not sure what is stopping you from adding those parameters as you have clearly mentioned in the post.. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/pmhFv/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You practically have it...  Just add your parameters to your function declaration, and replace the hard-coded values in the function with those parameter names:

```
var animateMe = function(targetElement, sX, sY, eX, eY, speed){
    $(targetElement).css({ left: sX+"px", top: sY+"px" }).fadeIn(200, function() {
        $(targetElement).animate({
            'left': eX+"px",
            'top': eY+"px"
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
                    animateMe(this, sX, sY, eX, eY, speed);
                })
            }
        }).fadeOut(200);
    });
};

animateMe($('#box1'), 300, 400, 40, 50, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bQVUH/

Answer (score 1):

You can `$.extend()` your options to provide defaults. And btw, you're wrapping your `targetElement` in jQuery twice.

```
var animateMe = function($el, options) {
    var o = $.extend({
        speed: 2000,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        endX: 100,
        endY: 100
    }, options);
    $el.css({
        left: o.startX,
        top: o.startY
    }).fadeIn(200, function() {
        $el.animate({
            'left': o.endX,
            'top': o.endY
        }, {
            duration: o.speed,
            complete: function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
                    animateMe(this, { speed: o.speed });
                });
            }
        }).fadeOut(200);
    });
};

// And then you run it like so

animateMe($('#el'), {
    speed: 3000,
    startX: 100,
    startY: 100,
    endX: 500,
    endY: 500
});
```